# Read a specific row on a csv file in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I've a function that gets a `.csv` file from parameter and a `myrownumber` (a number indicating a row of the .csv) of this array.

This returns the content of the line number `myrownumber` of the csv file.

```
private function readASpecificRow($filePath, $myrownumber)
{
    $rowImLookingFor = array();
    $f = fopen($filePath, "r");
    $i = 0;
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
    {
        $i ++;
        foreach ($line as $cell)
        {
            if ($i == $myrownumber)
            {
                array_push($rowImLookingFor, $cell);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose($f);

    return($rowImLookingFor);
}
```

This  is very innefficent as I've to iterate all the file until I find the row I'm looking for.

**Is there any other way to read directly the row number `myrownumber` of the `csv` file?**

PS: I know there are a lot of solutions with  will like to keep using `fgetcsv` because on the cells are some line breaks and with `fgetscsv` I keep the control of it. If i use `file` or whatever, the number of lines are different from the real number of lines of the csv due to the line breaks inside of some cells.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can take the `$i == $myrownumber` outside of the `foreach`. There's no need to check it for each cell, when it only changes on each row.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this doesn't provide you with a different solution but it could help with the assumed inefficiency.

I'd personally refactor the function to look more like this:

```
private function readASpecificRow($filePath, $myrownumber)
{
    $f = fopen($filePath, "r");
    $i = 0;
    $myrownumber = (int) $myrownumber; // ensure it's actually a number.
    while (($line = fgetcsv($f)) !== false)
    {
        if (++$i < $myrownumber) continue;
        fclose($f);
        return $line;
    }
    return false; // if the specified line wasn't there return false
}
```

It should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `file()` to get file by lines, than use `str_getcsv` to parse specific line to CSV.

Comment: Please, read the post, I would like to keep using `fgetscsv`. If I use `file()` the number of rows are different from the original `csv` file as they have line breaks on the cells.

Comment: @Avión Do you need these new lines later on?

Comment: What do you exacly mean?

Comment: @Avión Can you just replace these new lines to simple white-space character?

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple way to start reading directly row, but what you can try this way:

```
$pre_pos = <previous position>;
fseek($file, $pre_pos);
while(...) {
   fgetcsv(...);
   ...
}
$pre_pos = ftell($file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the entire file, but you can return early once your row is found to make it a bit more efficient. I can't see any need for the inner `foreach` loop on each line so that could be removed:

```
private function readASpecificRow($filePath, $myrownumber)
{
    $f = fopen($filePath, "r");

    for($i = 1; $line = fgetcsv($f); $i++) {
        if($i === $myrownumber) {
            fclose($f);
            return $line;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that this is not zero-based, so if `$myrownumber` is 1 it'll return the first line. Change the `$i = 1;` to `$i = 0` in the for loop to make it zero-based.